# Powershell rename files whilst maintaining the original file order

Tags: powershell, file, rename

I've got a set of files in the following format
[image: original file name]

I'd like to change the file names to the following format
[image: new file name]

I've used the following code:

`$i = 21

> > dir | ForEach-Object {$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('00816-101998-XX-A-2-50-{0:D3} Detalj.{1}' -f $i++,  $_.Extension)}`

This code starts renaming with file name A.10.11.11
How do I get it to start from the first file name i.e. 8.A.10.11.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question, I think this is what you intend to do.

The list of current filenames should be sorted by the **integer** value the filenames start with.

Next you want to rename them using a counter that starts with value 21
To do this, you can use a ForEach-Object loop, but the `-NewName` parameter of Rename-Item can also contain a scriptblock containing the action to perform.

```powershell
$i = 21
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.pdf' -File) | 
   Sort-Object @{Expression = {[int]($_.Name -split ' ')[0]}} | 
   Rename-Item -NewName { '00816-101998-XX-A-2-50-{0:D3} Detalj{1}' -f $script:i++, $_.Extension }
```

P.S. The image shows the filename starts with a number followed by a **space**, while in the question you give an example where the number is followed by a dot `.`. If that is the case in you file names, change `[int]($_.Name -split ' ')[0]` into `[int]($_.Name -split '\.')[0]`

<sup>1. We need to address and increment the value of the counter `$i` using the `$script:i` scoping syntax, otherwise `$i` does not exist in the NewName scriptblock

2. To avoid renaming files twice, enclose the `Get-ChildItem` part in the code in between brackets</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
param(
    $directory = "d:\tmp",
    [regex]$rx = "(?<=8.A.10.11.)\d+",
    [string]$newPrefix = "00816-101998-XX-A-2-50-"
)
<# 
8..20 | ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = Join-Path $directory -ChildPath "8.A.10.11.$_.pdf"
    Out-File -InputObject "some text" -FilePath $filePath -Encoding default
}
#>

Get-ChildItem $directory | ForEach-Object{
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$newPrefix$((($rx.Matches($_.BaseName)).value).padleft(3,'0'))$($_.Extension)"
}
```